# CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH separator : ':' or ';'?

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

When using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as an environnment variable, I have a weird behaviour, which I can't find in documentation.

I want to search the prefix path in two location, let's call them `/path/to/prefix1` and `/path/to/prefix2`.

- This doesn't work : `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/prefix1;/path/to/prefix2"`
- This **does** work : `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/prefix1:/path/to/prefix2"`

Obviously in Unix `PATH` variable use `:` as a separator, but in CMake list separator is `;`, like documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake-language.7.html#environment-variables). In the same link, its not written that environnment variables are an exception.

It also is explicitly written that `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is a [semicolon-separated list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html), which is confusing.

So what's going on here?

---

EDIT: It seems that when giving the argument from the command line, it does work only with `;` and not `:`, which is the opposite as using an environnment variable : e.g. `cmake .. -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/prefix1;/path/to/prefix2"` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal variable and the environment variable are treated differently and are documented separately. CMake tends to treat environment variables the same way as the system treats the `PATH` variable. CMake normal variables are typically semicolon-separated (the most notable exceptions are the `_FLAGS` variables, which are space-separated for historical and backwards compatibility reasons).

For the environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, the documentation says:

> This variable may hold a single prefix or a list of prefixes separated by `:` on UNIX or `;` on Windows (the same as the PATH environment variable convention on those platforms).

<sup>https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html</sup>

Meanwhile, for the normal `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, the documentation says:

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying installation prefixes to be searched by the `find_package()`, `find_program()`, `find_library()`, `find_file()`, and `find_path()` commands.

<sup>https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html</sup>

---

> which I can't find in documentation.

I found this simply by [searching "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/search.html?q=CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) in the documentation side-bar.